# multiplication dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe with rates for chaque id :

```
|id|rate|
----------
1  | 1
1  | 0.9
1  | 0.8
1  | 0.5
2  | 1
2  | 0.6
2  | 0.7
2  | 0.9
```

I want to multiply the rates for each id by a values but in a way to roll the result and multiply it by the next rate
like for example for the id 1 if we multiply the rates by the value 20
[1,0.9,0.8,0.5] *20 ==> [1,0.9,0.8,0.5]
i did this for each values

```
new_v=[rates[1]*20]
        for r in rates[1:]:
            new_v.append(new_v[-1]*r)
```

and Im wondering how to do it directly with the dataframe it should be faster way to make it

Comment: Your example data doesn't make much sense - 20 * 1 doesn't equal 1, and 20 * 0.5 doesn't equal 0.5, etc. Can you please show more clearly what you are hoping to achieve as output?

Answer (score 1):

You can group by ID and used the cumprod() method to apply cumulative product within each group

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        'rate': [1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.5, 1, 0.6, 0.7, 0.9]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

value = 20

# Group by 'id' and apply cumulative product within each group
df['result'] = df.groupby('id')['rate'].cumprod() * value

print(df)
```